# Find surfaces in 3d image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I'm working on a C++ project using a ToF camera. The camera is inside a room and has to detect walls, doors or other big planar surfaces. I'm currently using OpenCV but answers using other C++ libaries are also okay. What is a good algorithmn to detect the surfaces, also if they are rotated and aren't facing the camera directly. I've heard things like making a point cloud and using RANSAC. If you suggest me doing that please explain it in detail or provide a resource for explanation, because I don't know much about this topic (I'm a beginner in computer vision).

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/)?

[This tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php) shows how to find planar segments in a point-cloud using PCL.

Comment: Thank you, that looks pretty much like what I need. I don't know PCL, but I found lots of tutorials.